# How do I output the result from an sql query onto the screen in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-deployment

The following is the code I use to try and achieve this.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","booksmart_properties");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    else{

        echo "we connected";
    }

    // Perform queries 
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ListedProperties");
    $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);



    echo $result['*'];


    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I'm new to php and i'm sure it's something small, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($result as $key => $val)
{
     print $val;
}
```

Comment: You sir are a star

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

which will fetch a result row as an `associative array`

So you can call your result with a key to get a value.

example:

```
$result['id']
```

or to get all:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    print $value;
}
```